# Are there any tools for load / stress testing that can simulate image, video and audio uploads to Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-testing, stress-testing

As part of my web application users can upload photos, audio and video files from a Flash SWF to my EC2 based upload server. I want to find a tool that I can use to stress test the EC2 instance (which runs behind an Elastic Load Balancer). Are there any tools that can simulate concurrent users uploading a range of media files to PHP scripts on this server?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of cloud-hosted load-testing services out there which will do GET and simple POST requests en masse.  Very few support file upload.

[Browser Mob](https://browsermob.com/) is one that supports upload.  They're pricey though.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like that might be somewhat hard to implement. That isn't to say it doesn't exist, but think about it. You want to simulate 100 computers uploading? You need 100 connections from a single computer to the server. Actually, I could guess that someone has written a type of 'DDoS' program that actually tracks how much traffic it causes. I suggest looking into that. DDoS-ing your own site could give you the simulation you need.